Permission denied error while deleting the image from directory media/mobile_images
view.py:
if 'del_img2' in request.POST:
    product.image2.delete()
    img_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(product.image2))
    print(img_path)
    os.remove(img_path)
    product.image2.delete()

models.py
class Mobiles(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    actual_price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,blank=False)
    discount_price=models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)], default=0)
    selling_price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,default=0)
    review=models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)])
    features=models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=5000)
    days=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image1=models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to='mobile_images/')
    image2=models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='mobile_images/' , blank=True)

While clicking on submit button Image is deleting from db and media/mobile_images but throwing an error :
PermissionError at /admedit1/1
[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:\MyProjects\DjangoProjects\Elec&Gad\ElecAndGad\media\'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admedit1/1
Django Version: 4.2.5
Exception Type: PermissionError
Exception Value:
[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:\MyProjects\DjangoProjects\Elec&Gad\ElecAndGad\media\'
Local vars
D:\MyProjects\DjangoProjects\Elec&Gad\ElecAndGad\adminapp\views.py, line 105, in admedit1
os.remove(img_path)

Run your developement as administator, or right-click on the media folder within your project then goto Properties -> Security tab -> Edit and ensure the user running your development server (usually your username) has Full control permissions.
